# Android GPS get elevation gain and loss

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

With Android `LocationListener` I can get latitude, longitude, speed etc. But how do I get or calculate elevation gain and loss?

Comment: Hello @Vladyslav K any luck on elevation gain?you have accepted the answer can you please share a code snipet of elevation gain calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the altitude in the `LocationListener` if available.  Note that this is only available when using GPS.  If not available, `location.hasAltitude()` will be false.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)

{   
     double lon=location.getLongitude();  
     double lat=location.getLatitude();
     double alt=location.getAltitude();  // Return altitude in meters, 0.0 if not available
     ...
}
```

You may save the `alt` value to calcuate gain and loss afterwards.